# pixel art maker project jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

The code is about a webpage that takes grid height and width and creates it by clicking submit and then draw in the grid any shape by choosing the boxes depending on the chosen color. can someone explain to me what is wrong with my javascript code? 
[**code pen is here**](https://codepen.io/marwan46/pen/NYzXdr)

```
$('#submit').on('click', function makeGrid(event){
var r = $('#inputHeight').val();
var c = $('#inputWeight').val();
/*var grid = $('table');
var tr = '<tr></tr>';
var td = '<td></td>';*/
  for (var i=0; i<r; i++){
    $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
    for(var j=0; j<c; j++){
      $('tr:last-child').append('<td></td>');
    }
  }
 });

$('table').on('click',' tr td', function(){
$(this).css('background-color',$('colorPicker').val())
});
```

Comment: I see no `table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<input type="submit">` will [send a request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit) to the server. Which in turn will cause a redirect. 
You'll need to call `preventDefault()` and/or `return false` in your handler.

The jquery selector `$("#submit")` will look for an element with id `submit`, it isn't selecting the `<input type="submit">`, to fix, add the `id="submit"` to the `<input>`.

also, you might want to remove all children in the `<table>` when the button is pressed a second time. IE. `$("table").empty();`

```js
$("#submit").on("click", function makeGrid(event) {
  var r = $("#inputHeight").val();
  var c = $("#inputWeight").val();
  $("table").empty();
  /*var grid = $('table');
  var tr = '<tr></tr>';
  var td = '<td></td>';*/
  for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    $("table").append("<tr></tr>");
    for (var j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      $("tr:last-child").append("<td></td>");
    }
  }

  $("table tr td").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", $("#colorPicker").val());
  });
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Monoton;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
  margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
  height: 20px;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

  <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
  <form id="sizePicker">
    Grid Height:
    <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
    <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="1">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
  </form>

  <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
  <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

  <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
  <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

  <script src="designs.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that helped a lot but I still face an issue when i open it on google or explorer and i insert the table width and height it doesn't show the canvas !!? what do you think the problem even though here it's working fine

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Is the CSS not being loaded?